# PHP changing content in header

Tags: php, html

I have a site where the pages have the following structure:

```
<?php
    include('header.php');
?>

Content goes here

<?php
    include('footer.php');
?>
```

In the header I have a div that contains anything that is wider than the page itself. This div is above the main content:

```
<? if ($slider == true){ ?>

    <div id="slider">
       Content wider than page goes here
    </div>
```

If I set $slider to true on any page, the above div will show. Now, I want to be able to edit the content of this div from any page. How do I do this? Simply adding a variable like $slider_content and then including it in the header did not work.

Comment: In your sample HTML, did you mean to include `header.php` twice?

Comment: How about creating a function that takes the content as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's what you mean...

```
<?php
    $slider_content = 'foo';

    include('header.php');
?>

Content goes here

<?php
    include('footer.php');
?>
```

And your slider:

```
<div id="slider">
   <?=$slider_content?>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked. I tried the exact same approach myself, but it didn't work. Only difference was the = in <?=$slider_content?>. Can you explain why that works, and not using the = doesn't?

Comment: <?=$variable?> outputs given $variable. It's the same as writing <?php echo $variable?>. Please accept my answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add something like this in your included header.php:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['edit-content'])): ?>
    make the content editable here
<?php else: ?>
<div id="slider">
   Content wider than page goes here
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then you simply add a edit button if the goal here was to edit the actual content of your slider from any given page.